# To use the json value declared in controller in module of that controller in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have retrieved one json file in my login controller whose values I'm using in all the html files of my application but now I want to use the same JSON object in module.js files on all other pages.... can someone please suggest me how to fix this..This is the function which I've written in my controller, in which I want to use translation value in different page's module.js file.
Thanks in advance!!

```
 function getTranslation(filname) {
            var languageFilePath = 'app/pages/translations/translation_' + filname + '.json';
            $resource(languageFilePath).get(function (data) {
                $scope.translation = data;
            });
         }
```

Comment: Use Services to manage it

Comment: How will you call the service with different module.js without the file name??

Comment: I want to use  $scope.translation in my module.js file as  
 title:'translation.MANAGE_INVENTORY'